# Python Multiple Dictonary Values into one List

Tags: python

so im using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to read multiple .xmls in a Folder.

i extract the desired Attributes using `x.attrib` and put those into a variable.

```
attributes = x.attrib
```

The stored information comes in multiple dictonaries:

```
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_1'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_2'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_3'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_4'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_5'}
```

Now i've tried to iterate through all of them and putting all Key5 Values into a single List:

```
li = []
for d in attributes:
    li.append(attributes.get("Key5"))
```

Current output is:

```
['Value_5', 'Value_5', 'Value_5', 'Value_5', 'Value_5']
```

Output should be:

```
['Value_1', 'Value_2', 'Value_3', 'Value_4', 'Value_5']
```

Full Code for clarity:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

path = "directory/here"

    for filenames in os.listdir(path):
    if filenames.endswith('.xml'):
        fullnames = os.path.join(path, filenames)
        tree = ET.parse(fullnames)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for x in root[2:]:
            attributes = x.attrib
            l = []
            for d in attributes:
                l.append(attributes.get("Key5"))
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You mean `dict.get("Key5")` as dict is the loop variable.?

Comment: Do **not** use built-in types as variable names (e.g., dict, list) unless you're a masochist

Comment: Do you have a dictionary of 5 dictionaries or..? i.e shouldn't your output be a list containing 5 lists ?

Comment: from what i can tell x.attrib generates a dictonary containing a dictonary for every .xml that it reads, so yes i'm assuming its 5

Comment: added full code for clarity

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

path = "directory/here"

for filenames in os.listdir(path):
    if filenames.endswith('.xml'):
        fullnames = os.path.join(path, filenames)
        tree = ET.parse(fullnames)
        root = tree.getroot()
        l = []
        for x in root[2:]:
            d = x.attrib # <- .attrib method returns a dictionary, not the list
            l.append(d.get("Key5")) # <-- note we are referring to "d" here
        print(l)
```

Note: Using "list" and "dict" as variable names is a not good idea because they are reserved names in Python, so I've renamed them, but maybe "result" and "item" is better

Note 2: You mentioned in the comments that the code produces AttributeError, which means `attributes = x.attrib` doesn't return a list of dictionaries as you expected.

Comment: Thanks, im aware of that, i just used them to explain the issue as easy as possible :)

Comment: for some reason im getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'" when i try it with d instead of attributes

Comment: Then `attributes` is either not the structure you have written or contains JSON-strings instead of dictionaries

Comment: `attributes` is (variable) attributes: dict[str, str] | Any and `d` when stated turns into (variable) d: str | Any @CutePoison

Comment: If I read it correctly then attributes contains a string as values, and you need them to be a dictionary. See my update answer below

Comment: What you see if you do ``` for x in root[2:]: print(x.attrib)```?

Comment: @svfat if i print that i get the dictonaries:
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_1'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_2'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_3'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_4'}
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_5'}

Comment: also print(type(x.attrib)) gives back <class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>

Comment: ok, that means the x.attrib is not the list of dictionaries but a dictionary itself, I'll update the code in the answer

Comment: that only returns 1 value like my previous code, it doesn't iterate through all the different keys

Comment: it doesn't iterate through all the different keys, do you mean it should also iterate over Key1, Key2 etc.?

Comment: `x.attrib` returns 5 total dictonaries as you can see with `print(type(x.attrib))`

Comment: yes it should grab the last key out of every dictonary

Comment: could you add a data sample to the question? I mean orginal xml

Comment: what will be the output if you do: ```for i,x in enumerate(root[2:]): print(i, x.attrib, type(x.attrib))```?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/e0gfyc heres an example file, they're all structured the same. The Attribute thats supposed to be extracted out of every .xml is the value in ProjectID

Comment: @svfat also did your print statement:
`0 {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_1'} <class 'dict'>
0 {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_2'} <class 'dict'>
0 {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_3'} <class 'dict'>
0 {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_4'} <class 'dict'>
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_5'} <class 'dict'>`

Comment: @Bronko great, we are close to solve that. try `for x in enumerate(root[2:]): print(x.attrib.get("Key5"))` now

Comment: @svfat `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'attrib'`

Comment: x by the way was `(0, <Element '{http://www.lithotechnics.com}Project' at 0x0000024D34455A90>)` for every .xml

Comment: I've made a typo `for x in root[2:]: print(x.attrib.get("Key5"))` sorry

Comment: @svfat `None
None
None
None
None`

Comment: @Bronko, that's strange, I don't get it. Then: `for x in root[2:]: print(x.attrib, x.attrib.get("Key5"))`

Comment: @svfat nvm i'm an idiot its:
`{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_1'} Value_1
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_2'} Value_2
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_3'} Value_3
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_4'} Value_4
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4', 'Key5': 'Value_5'} Value_5`

Comment: but as soon as i try `lst.append(x.attrib.get("Key5"))` it only grabs one of the 5 values

Comment: ok so replace whole `for x in... ` line with `print([x.attrib.get("Key5") for x in root[2:]])` what will it print?

Comment: @svfat it prints all values in seperate lists, close :)

Comment: @Bronko If I understood correctly, did you get a single list with nested lists inside? then I assume you need `lst = [x.attrib["Key5"][0] for x in root[2:]]` (use [0] to get the first value from the nested list) Let me know if I understood you wrong

Comment: @svfat no it doesn't give a single nested list, `print(type([x.attrib.get("Key5") for x in root[2:]]))` gives 5 lists `<class 'list'>`, each one containing one Key Value for example `['123'], ['456'], ['789'], ['654'], ['321']`

Comment: @svfat already tried multiple things like extend() to get them into one list, but the issue seems to be having multiple lists in one single variable

Answer (score 2):

The most pythonic way would be using list-comprehension

**EDIT**
If I read your comment correctly then `x.attrib` is a dictionary of strings i.e we need to convert it to a dictionary using the `json` library.

Then we need to extract all values from each dictionary and save them in a list

```py
import json

l = [json.loads(d).get("Key5") for d in x.attrib]
```

But as @svfat writes, do *not* use stuff like `dict`,`list` as a variable names

Comment: tried that aswell, threw another error at me json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Try print the type of the first "dictionary" i.e `type(next(attributes.values()))`

Comment: print(type(next(attributes.values())))
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not an iterator